# Update nested array objects based on a property in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB collection which has documents which look like this:

```
{
    createdTimestamp: 111111111111,
    items: [{
        itemName: 'Name 1',
        quantity: 10
    }, {
        itemName: 'Name 2'
        quantity: 20
    }]
}
```

Now, I want to update all documents so that `itemName: 'Name 1'` would be updated to `itemName: 'New Name'`.
After an update, the above document should look like as below:

```
{
    createdTimestamp: 111111111111,
    items: [{
        itemName: 'New Name',
        quantity: 10
    }, {
        itemName: 'Name 2'
        quantity: 20
    }]
}
```

Is there any way to do this, without iterating over all documents myself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [`$ positional`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)  operator  to update an array element and with `multi: true` option you can update multiple document with the same match

```
db.collection.update(
  { 'items': { '$elemMatch': { 'itemName': 'Name 1' }}},
  { '$set': { 'items.$.itemName': 'New Name' }},
  { 'multi': true }
)
```

and with the mongodb **3.6** [`arrayFilters`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/update/)

```
db.collection.update(
  { 'items': { '$elemMatch': { 'itemName': 'Name 1' }}},
  { '$set': { 'items.$[item].itemName': 'New Name' }},
  { 'arrayFilter': [{ 'item.itemName': 'Name 1' }], 'multi': true }
)
```

Comment: It worked. Had to do a small change: `'$elemMatch': {itemName: 'Name 1'}`

Answer (score 1):

you can use mongoDb [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/)

```
db.collection.update(
  { },
  { "$set": { "items.$[elem].itemName": 'new Name' } },
  { "arrayFilters": [{ "elem.itemName": 'Name 1' }], "multi": true }
)
```