# I'm wanting to update fields in nested array in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

here's my document:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5eb5f0a9d985888edb0523b0"
},
"subs": [{
    "name": "list1",
    "count": "0"
}, {
    "name": "list2",
    "count": "0"
}, {
    "name": "list3",
    "count": "0"
}, {
    "name": "list4",
    "count": "0"
}]
}
```

I'm using mongojs currently.  I'd like to be able to for instance, find "list2" and increment the count associated with it.  I have tried all day and can't seem to figure it out.

any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think is using array filters: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/update/#update-command-arrayfilters - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51605347/update-nested-array-objects-based-on-a-property-in-mongodb

Comment: is you try to update the values only using mongojs provided functions or just need to update those values by using javascript functions?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried ? And as @AravindaMeewalaarachchi pointed do you want a raw mongodb query or you want to use the library ?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you. I have use programmatic approach to solve your problem.

```
let payload = {
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5eb5f0a9d985888edb0523b0"
},
"subs": [{
    "name": "list1",
    "count": "0"
}, {
    "name": "list2",
    "count": "0"
}, {
    "name": "list3",
    "count": "0"
}, {
    "name": "list4",
    "count": "0"
}]
}

let fields = ["list2","list4"];

fields.forEach((element)=>{
    for(let i=0; i<payload.subs.length; i++){
         if(element===payload.subs[i]["name"]){
            let value = parseInt(payload.subs[i]["count"]);
            payload.subs[i]["count"] = (++value).toString();
         }
    }
})

console.log(payload.subs)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5eb5f0a9d985888edb0523b0"
},
"subs": [{
    "name": "list1",
    "count": 0
}, {
    "name": "list2",
    "count": 0
}, {
    "name": "list3",
    "count": 0
}, {
    "name": "list4",
    "count": 0
}]
}
```

The answer is not based on mongojs but the syntax below should assist you.

```
db.collection.updateOne(({"subs.name":"list2"},{$inc:{"subs.$.count":1}})
```

Make sure that your count is `int32` not a string. `"Count": 0` not `"Count":"0"`