# How to find and update an array in the object of array document using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

A query to how to update the **items** array of object by

- finding the breed `dachshund`
- update the `name` to `new-dog`
- `updatedAt` to the current time

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60053b74aa72f132cb75b8b6"),
    "clientId" : "test",
    "items" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60053b74aa72f132cb75b8b7"),
            "name" : "tommy",
            "breed" : "dachshund",
            "createdAt" : 1610955636,
            "updatedAt" : 1610955636
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60053b74aa72f132cb75b8b8"),
            "name" : "mickey",
            "breed" : "husky",
            "createdAt" : 1610955636,
            "updatedAt" : 1610955636
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60053b74aa72f132cb75b8b9"),
            "name" : "whiskey",
            "breed" : "dachshund",
            "createdAt" : 1610955636,
            "updatedAt" : 1610955636
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60053b74aa72f132cb75b8ba"),
            "name" : "milo",
            "breed" : "bulldog",
            "createdAt" : 1610955636,
            "updatedAt" : 1610955636
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60053b74aa72f132cb75b8bb"),
            "name" : "pooh",
            "breed" : "poodle",
            "createdAt" : 1610955636,
            "updatedAt" : 1610955636
        }
    ],
    "shopname" : "myshopify"
}]
```

Comment: Could you please show your try, you can use update command with [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/).

Comment: model.updateOne({_id: ObjectId("60053b74aa72f132cb75b8b6")},
{arrayFilters: [{'el.breed': 'dachshund'}]},{$set: {'items.name': 'new-dog'}})

Comment: You query is not valid, you can read documentation, see similar [Update nested array objects based on a property in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51605347/update-nested-array-objects-based-on-a-property-in-mongodb) this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
const curDatetime = moment(moment();

model.updateOne(
{_id: ObjectId("60053b74aa72f132cb75b8b6")}, 
{
   arrayFilters: [
     {'el.breed': 'dachshund'}
   ]
},
{
   $set: {
     'items.$[el].name': 'new-dog',
     'items.$[el].updatedAt': curDatetime
   }
}, "multi": true)
```